# Send/Receive broadcast on Ethernet Android

Tags: android, networking, broadcast, ethernet

Use case is this I'm making an app for tablets that will act as a intercom for example i have 10 android tablets in various areas of my house.
I want to send audio broadcasts to all the devices connected to my network via Ethernet.

Comment: What does PoE have to do with your application? It doesn't seem to have anything more to do with the application than using a power cord.

Comment: i just wanted to make clear that target device is android tablet wall mount with power

Comment: That should not affect your application in any way. It doesn't, or shouldn't, care how you power your device (PoE, power line, battery, etc.). I think putting that in your question is gratuitous and confusing.

Comment: yes you are right let me edit my question

Comment: A broadcast must be inspected by _every_ host on a LAN. If you have other devices on the same LAN, you will be interrupting them, too, even though they do not run your application. That is why multicast was invented. Multicast is a broadcast only to hosts which want to participate in the multicast group. You could have a general multicast group to which every tablets subscribes, and separate multicast groups for connections between two tablets, e.g. bedroom - kitchen, that would not send audio to the other tablets in the house to allow private conversations.

Comment: @RonMaupin yeah that's a very good sugguestion - Thanks but i still want to send a broadcast